# SKMaps: How do I initialise a search using "SKAddressSearchSettings" class?

Tags: android, search, skmaps

I am trying to include an address search inside my application developed in Eclipse using SKMaps (for Android). I believe I should be using the SKSearchManager but it does not specify any method that accepts SKAddressSearchSettings as an argument.

In the documentation it says that SKMultiSearchSettings can be used to search for a Country > City > Street but in does not have the required setter methods. The only one there is setSearchTerm() which does not seem to do the job.

Is this a genuine problem or is there some other way around it?

Answer (score 0):

For the search to work you need to have the maps downloaded as the search only work with the "offline" maps: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec019

This should also be the behaviour of the demo projects (http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download)

Once you download the map you should start getting back results. **Note:** you'll be searching through OSM data and that's (unfortunately) not the best when it comes to addressability)